# hamcrest - compare items in the collection

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

Can anyone explain to me how hamcrest compares collections and and what the different methods from the library are for?
I am trying to understand how does *IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder#containsInAnyOrder* method work.
There are three overloaded methods in [IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.html)  class:

- `containsInAnyOrder(T... items)`
- `containsInAnyOrder(Matcher<? super T>... itemMatchers)`
- `containsInAnyOrder(java.util.Collection<Matcher<? super T>> itemMatchers)`

My test case:

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class HamcrestCollections {

    @Test
    public void myTest(){

        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("one","two","four");

        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("two","one");

        // This doesn't compile
        assertThat(actual, Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(expected));

        assertThat(actual, Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));
    }
}
```

The first assertion doesn't compile, the error is:

```
Error:(19, 9) java: no suitable method found for assertThat(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>)
    method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
        upper bound(s): java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.util.List<java.lang.String>>,java.lang.Object)
```

I really do not catch what's going on in this message.

---

I found that it must be converted to the array in order to work (the second assertion in the example):

```
Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));
```

I suppose that in this case this method from the library is used:`containsInAnyOrder(T... items)`, is that true ?
But how remaining methods from `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder` can be used ? Is there any way to compare collections without converting them to the array?

Comment: Which JUnit and Hamcrest version are you using?

Comment: @hovanessyan I'm using Hamcrest 1.3 with JUnit 4.12 and its `assertThat()` method works just fine. After all it delegates to Hamcrest's `MatcherAssert.assertThat()`. Maybe it's a mix of hamcrest library versions. @krokodilko Is this a maven poroject, can you share the pom? Alternatively can you share the versions of the libraries you're using, and if possibly the runtime classpath?

Comment: @Morfic it really depends on the JUnit and Hamcrest versions. In Junit 5 they have removed the asserThat from JUnit's Assertions, in favor of using  directly the Hamcrest's asserThat - and it's not without a reason

Comment: @hovanessyan my comment was regarding your initial suggestion, which I guess changed :-). While I don't disagree that they did it for a reason (there are probably be more than the following), I suspect they wanted to break the [dependency of JUnit on Hamcrest](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit%7C4.12%7Cjar) and allow [more 3rd party libraries](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions-third-party). It's just a hunch that there could be a Hamcrest version mix-up, but until we can reproduce the CP we won't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles just fine in the first form with JDK 1.8.0_12, Hamcrest 1.3 and JUnit 4.12, although it does not produce the expected result due to a *gotcha* I'll be explaining below.

I can only guess that you may have a mix of library versions, or jdk, or something of the sorts. However, I believe it does not really matter, because of that *gotcha* I was mentioning.

---

> Can anyone explain to me how hamcrest compares collections and and what the different methods from the library are for?

In short, you can either supply your own array/collection of matchers, or an array of items for which it will create matchers. Afterwards, the actual items are validated against the resulting matcher list.

If you check [the sources](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/hamcrest-java-1.3/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.java) you'll see that the `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder` constructor accepts a collection of matchers:

```
public IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder(Collection<Matcher<? super T>> matchers) {
    this.matchers = matchers;
}
```

... while the methods you were wondering about are *factory methods* which return an `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder` instance. One is deprecated and I have skipped it. Then we have the following 2, where the first delegates to the second without anything fancy going on:

```
public static <T> Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(Matcher<? super T>... itemMatchers) {
    return containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList(itemMatchers));
}

public static <T> Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(Collection<Matcher<? super T>> itemMatchers) {
    return new IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder<T>(itemMatchers);
}
```

... and finally we have:

```
public static <T> Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(T... items) {
    List<Matcher<? super T>> matchers = new ArrayList<Matcher<? super T>>();
    for (T item : items) {
        matchers.add(equalTo(item));
    }

    return new IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder<T>(matchers);
}
```

As you see, a matcher is created for every item, which is somewhat a [gotcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming)):

- if you pass an array of arguments, you'll get a matcher for each item

`assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder("one", "two", "four"));` yelds:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable over ["one", "two", "four"] in any order
     but: No item matches: "four" in ["two", "one"]
```

- if you pass a list, it'll count as a 1 argument array, and only 1 matcher will be created, for the list itself

`assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four")))` yelds:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable over [<[one, two, four]>] in any order
     but: Not matched: "two"
```

Notice the subtle difference?

---

> I found that it must be converted to the array in order to work (the
>   second assertion in the example):
>
> `Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));` I suppose that in
>   this case this method from the library is used:`containsInAnyOrder(T...
>   items)`, is that true ?
>
> But how remaining methods from `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder` can be
>   used ? Is there any way to compare collections without converting them
>   to the array?

Just use the *inline form* as it was intended: `assertThat(myList, containsInAnyOrder("one", "two", "four"))`. I suppose this offers better readability and avoids unnecessary variables or superfluous coding, such as the *expected* collection. Usually you need to check for a few items, not hundreds, right?